# Difference entre journée et Journée (en J Majuscule)

Tags: sens

J'ai fait le dicté sur http://dictee.tv5monde.com et j'ai taper a la place de Journée -> journée, j'ai arrivé a cette error :

> Le 8 mars est la Journée internationale de la femme (**ici on utilise
>   une majuscule car le mot « journée » a un sens particulier**).

[image: Journée -> journée]

Quelqu'un savez c'est quoi ce **sens particulier**, et ou on peux utilisé journée et Journée en **J majuscule**?

Comment: Je pense qu'il faut comprendre que l’expression est une citation du titre de l'évènement en question. En tant que *titre*, on la fait commencer par une majuscule. On peut voir aussi *Journée Internationale des Droits des Femmes* par endroits. Là, il s'agit du nom d'une manifestation. Le choix est arbitraire. Très courant en anglais, pas forcément en français.

Comment: ah d'accord @jcm69 pouvez-vous mettre ça comme une reponse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just that it's a proper name. "International Women's Day", compared to "a given day".

It may look strange to you that only the J is capitalized, and not I or F. This is because French titles only capitalize the first word, not every word.

> I'm reading *The Little Prince*.
>
> Je lis *Le petit prince*.

Comment: sense, even ;-)